# Creating a Android OSGI bundle with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, osgi

I have a issue with Android, Eclipse and OSGI.

On a Android 2.1 device is a OSGI container running successfully, but for the bundle i need to use the android API so there are no imports missing. In my opinion the android.jar is already available by the system, so he doesn't need to be imported.

I'm not familiar with configure the build path.

Can someone point me in the right direction to solve my import problem?

Thanks,

Yours sincerely,

Jelmert

Answer (score 0):

you have to add all the imported packages in the `Manifest` file of your bundle (including Android packages).